# provide old content, while changing

Tags: apache, http, curl

Imagine I have a file with a list. Frequently, this file/list is updated/changed. While changing, I would like to provide the old version, until the change is complete.

I have an Apache server and I use cURL to change the file.

**Problem**: When I use `PUT` to update the list and meanwhile use `GET` to get the same list, I will get the intermediate state of the file at precisely this moment.

**Question**: Is there a way to provide the old file as long as the write/`PUT` process is not terminated (well)?

Thanks for any hint or further discussion of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to ensure that the 'new' list is complete and ready to go before you discard the old list. At a very high level, I imagine something like this:

Get -> Return 'File A'

Put -> Create 'File B'. When complete, delete 'File A' and rename 'File B' to 'File A'.